# Changing path class by reading data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me preface it by saying I'm totally out of my element; since we're in the process of restructuring at work I need to pick up some additional responsibilities - like for example making some visualizations.

So my problem is as follows: I have an svg map, where each of 200+ paths has its own id. I also have a json file with multiple attributes. So what I want to do is, when you press for example a button, each path gets a class based on json file where json id = path id. Then the path gets filled with the color from css file.

```
[{
  "id": "a",
  "up": "users: 124"
  "class": "test"
},
{
  "id": "b",
  "up": "users: 4"
  "class": "test2"
}];
```

and

```
$('#button').on("click", function() {
$('.test').css({ fill: "#f6eff7" });
$('.test2').css({ fill: "#a6bddb" });
```

and

```
<path id="a" class="" d="..." />
<path id="b" class="" d="..." />
<button class="btn" id="button">2018</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `click` on your `<button>` and add the classes using `Array#forEach` to loop through your data:

```js
let data = [{
    "id": "a",
    "up": "users: 124",
    "class": "test"
  },
  {
    "id": "b",
    "up": "users: 4",
    "class": "test2"
  }
];

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  data.forEach(current => {
    document.querySelector('path#' + current.id).classList.add(current.class);
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  fill: red;
}

.test2 {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg>
<path id="a" class="" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
<path id="b" class="" d="M100 0 L75 100 L125 100 Z" />
</svg>
<button class="btn" id="button">Add classes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var arr = [{
  "id": "a",
  "up": "users: 124",
  "class": "test"
},
{
  "id": "b",
  "up": "users: 4",
  "class": "test2"
}];

$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  for(var index = 0; index < arr.lenth; i++) {
    $("#" + arr[i].id).addClass(arr[i].class);
  }
});
```